# How to align div content in specific position using Css?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```js
body {
  margin: 0;
  font - family: Arial,
  Helvetica,
  sans - serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background - color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: # f2f2f2;
  text - align: center;
  padding: 14 px 16 px;
  text - decoration: none;
  font - size: 17 px;
}

.topnav a: hover {
    background - color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }

  .topnav a.active {
    background - color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* select dropdown css code */
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: # 5 c6664;
    background - image: none;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 0.5e m;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font - size: 1e m;
    font - family: "Open Sans", sans - serif;
  }
select::-ms - expand {
    display: none;
  }
  .select {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 20e m;
    height: 3e m;
    line - height: 3;
    background: #5c6664;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
.select::after {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: # 2 b2e2e;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer - events: none;
    transition: 0.25 s all ease;
  }
  .select: hover::after {
    color: #23b499;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Red FMTuning</a>
  <a href="#news" class="aligntune">Choose a tune from ur favourite</a>
  <a href="#contact">
    <div class="select">
      <select name="format" id="format">
        <option selected>Choose a book format</option>
        <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
        <option value="txt">txt</option>
        <option value="epub">ePub</option>
        <option value="fb2">fb2</option>
        <option value="mobi">mobi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#about" class="alignout">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" @click="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image: Issue with content divs]

As in the above image, u can see the , all the elements like "tuning", "Choose a tune from ur favourite" , "Choose a book format", ""About". All the contents are not in proper shape. and mainly the dropdown("Choose a book format") it is in not aligned according to other content. and when click on dropdown also. it is overlapping on content.

I need to align all the elements until it reaches to some 1200px  like below.

[image]

Code:- https://jsfiddle.net/se8pa7m3/2/

Comment: For a start you have invalid HTML. An `<a>` tag can not contain interactive conten, e.g. `select` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrapped "Choose a book format", "About" `<div class="topnav-inner-wrap">` and applied flexbox css on `.topnav` & `.topnav-inner-wrap`

**Working Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/k2beLnrv/

```js
function myFunction(){
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav > a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a,
  .topnav.responsive .topnav-inner-wrap {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .topnav > a:not(:first-child), .topnav .topnav-inner-wrap {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a,
  .topnav.responsive .topnav-inner-wrap {
    float: none;
    display: block !important;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* select dropdown css code */
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: #5c6664;
  background-image: none;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 20em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  background: #5c6664;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
.select::after {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: #2b2e2e;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.25s all ease;
}
.select:hover::after {
  color: #23b499;
}

.topnav-inner-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Red FMTuning</a>
      <a href="#news" class="aligntune">Choose a tune from ur favourite</a>
      <div class="topnav-inner-wrap">
      <a href="#contact">
      <div class="select">
          <select name="format" id="format">
            <option selected>Choose a book format</option>
            <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
            <option value="txt">txt</option>
            <option value="epub">ePub</option>
            <option value="fb2">fb2</option>
            <option value="mobi">mobi</option>
          </select>
        </div></a
      >
      <a href="#about" class="alignout">About</a>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are correct but, I am trying to achieve the Responsive navigation bar. when i applied your styles. and when screen reaches to 1200px. dropdown is not inside of nav-icon. and inside nav icon also design is changed. (inside nav-bar ) icon it should show items like vertically.

My complete code with functionality https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-leftpad-cc7cm?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: it should behave like, When 1200px. align like above mentioned format. and when it reaches to below 1200px . then nav-icon will display. so clicking on that , the same elements need to display vertically one by one

Comment: I have updated the CSS and demo link. I hope now your issue is resolved. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sxphfL3/1/). You can use `flexbox` for this scenario. Add these properties to your `topnav`:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

`align-items` is used to align the items vertically, and `justify-content` is used to space them equally. You can only use both properties if you've set the `display` to `flex`.

More on `flexbox` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content:space-between;` in the parent class